# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function acf_add_options_page()_сайт выдает такую ошибку

Tags: php, wordpress, плагин

Сайт на WP, при поиске ошибки по ошибки отключили
плагин Advanced Custom Fields PRO, после чего в админ панели и на
самом сайте выпала ошибка: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to
undefined function acf_add_options_page() in /home/ ... далее страницы
сайта....и далее путь до файла /functions.php on line 58

В файле functions код вот такой, это 58 строка:

//OPTIONS PAGE

```
if( function_exists('acf_add_options_page') ){
$args = array(
    'page_title' => 'Настройки сайта',
    'menu_title' => '',
    'menu_slug' => '',
    'capability' => 'edit_posts',
    'position' => false,
    'parent_slug' => '',
    'icon_url' => false,
    'redirect' => true,
    'post_id' => 'options',
    'autoload' => false,);
acf_add_options_page($args);}
```

Comment: И в чем вопрос? Не знаете, как закомментировать код? Я уж не говорю о том, что приведённый код не может вызвать фатальную ошибку.

Comment: Вопрос описан, как исправить данную проблему, так как сайт рухнул. Если вам кажется, что данная ошибка не приводит к последствия, то значит вы с ней не сталкивались, тогда и отвечать на данный вопрос думаю вам не нужно, найдутся более знающие люди.

Comment: Это вы мне - про более знающих людей? Ну-ну )))